# Filtering Array of Objects With ng-click

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I am having troubles with getting this to work and I do not get why as no errors are coming up.

I have an array with data in it, in each set of object in the array there is an attribute called `is_open`. If it is open then it is set to `1` otherwise it is `0`.

I call this method in my `ng-click`.

```
$scope.hide = function()
{
    $scope.hideFilter = $scope.data.filter(function(element)
    {
        return (element.is_open == 1);
    });
}
```

Whenever I click my button nothing happens. The array is not filtered.

Comment: are you sure you're not confusing `data` array with `hideFilter` array? I mean which array do you expect to be filtered?

Comment: I found this myself, what a silly mistake. Also appreciate it for pointing it out.